# PC hard locks on motherboard splash screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot

So I recently suffered a nasty computer crash after trying to remove a theme pack I was using, and nothing would get me back to accessible windows (not safe mode, system restore, etc.) so I backed up everything I could think of to another drive, using a Linux cd, and reinstalled windows 8(point 0) from my cd, intending to skip straight to 10 from that. It installed fine, I did a check for updates so that it gets the reserve window's 10 option, and did an Update and Restart. So, it updated (38 updates) and then rebooted, and hard locked at the MB logo, I can't figure out any way to get it to boot, I can't reach BIOs, windows recovery, or anything. I have tried unplugging everything except monitor to no avail, I will try resetting my CMOS battery I guess tomorrow, does anyone know what might cause this or solutions?

Note that while some things are backed up to an external drive, a lot is on a partition so I'm really hoping it's not a drive failure.

Thanks in advance, 
Nico